# Why can not resolve the type

Tags: scala

I have following sample functor:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

object Functor {
  implicit val listFunctor: Functor[List] = new Functor[List] {
    def map[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: (A) => B): List[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
}

Functor.listFunctor.map(List(1,2,3,4))(_ + _)
```

The compiler complain on last line:

```
Error:(29, 47) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
Functor.listFunctor.map(List(1,2,3,4))(_ + _)
                                       ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the `map` definition takes one function from A to B, you are using a partial function with two parameters, e.g. `(_.toString)` would work.

Comment: I want to make an addition to them self, for example 1 + 1, 2 + 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ + _` is a function taking two arguments and returning their sum, this is not what `map` expects. Try the following instead:

```
Functor.listFunctor.map(List(1,2,3,4))(i => i + i)
```